# Firebase. What is better (free pricing): one big document or a lot of small documents?

Tags: angular, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a highschool teacher and I am currently developing a web for the 'highschool museum', which contains historical things. The fact is the museum has approx. 1000 items, and I suppose it will have more in the future. We want to use the free plan as the site is not super visited.

My question is how could I structure the database for minifying the reads? Besides I want to use a cache system, I would like to know if is better to have one big document with an array of all JSON inside, or well a document for each item from the list. I don't really know how exactly works the reads and writes for the free pricing plan.

I know I could do it with SQL and other technologies, but we want to do it with Firebase.

Thank you

Comment: I had the same issue a while ago, and actually decided to use Atlas Mongodb. No usage charges, just a limit on db size 512MB) for the free plan. They don’t even need your cc details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with storing details of multiple items in a single document is that you won't be able to utilize most of the queries. For example, you just want to get items added in museum in year 2020, you could do so easily using `where("year", "==" 2020)` assuming each item has it's own document with a year field. But if multiple items are stored in a single document then you would be fetching a most of the documents and then manually find the document where this particular item is. However this solution might work for you use case. Also checkout ["Reduce Firestore Costs"](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-firestore-costs-8cb712473e83) by @Alex.

You can also enable [Firestore offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline). If you users will be making same queries e.g. top 10 most viewed items or something similar, you can also consider using [data bundles](https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles) but you need to use server side SDKs for those (that might require Cloud functions or a backend environment).

Comment: Yes, I know that the filter is it a problem, but would be count just as 1 read? I could simply do filters using functional programming once loaded all the documents. I'll check the Firestore offline persistence. Thanks.

Comment: @Jotan yes that works. But do note that each document has a limit of 1 MB so you might need to store multiple such documents.

Comment: Well, If this works.. I prefer to use 10 big documents instead of 800 smaller. I 'win' 790 reads. I don't know If I explain myself

Comment: @Jotan yes, as long as you don't need really advanced queries, it works.

Comment: Perfect, so I'll give this a try, using the caché system. Thank you so much!